# Logic of LinkedList in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, structure, dev-c++

I've just started studying Data Structures and today I've watched a video about LinkedList in C. I could understand most of the things that were explained thanks to knowledge that I gained throughout my classes yet I couldn't understand one thing.

In the video, it's explained as, we create a structure of node and then we allocate our memory for it. Let's say we have 2 data types inside of it as integer and pointer. Let's say we have 5 nodes like this and each pointer keeps the address of the next node. There is no problem up to now. But what I couldn't understand is that, how this pointers work for keeping the adress of the next element whenever we call the function. How it passes through the other elements that might be between the head node and the other that we seek? If someone can explain, it would be really good.

Thank you.

Comment: The pointer doesn't keeps the address as soon as program terminates or you `free`d the memory. But while the program is running, the pointer has its value, so it points to that memory location allocated by the system. So, each time you call the function, it dereferences that mem. address.

Comment: Let's assume it starts with `head->next->next->int`. So, here it is passing from `head` to `next` which contains another memory address, so it moves to the `next` address and so on, then you find your `int` and it stops. **Conclusion**: It starts from `head` and goes through the `next` pointer to the `pointer` where your value is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers don't "pass through" other elements. Each element simply stores the address of the next element.

It's like an Easter egg hunt with clues, where each egg has a clue about the next egg. (Except they're not clues, they just tell you where the egg is)

In the kitchen there's a note (the variable `head`) saying "there's an egg in the mailbox". That's the head pointer.

In the mailbox there's an egg (`data`) and a note (`next`) saying "there's an egg in the oven". That's the first node.

In the oven there's an egg (`data`) and a note (`next`) saying "there's an egg under the car".
That's the second node.

Under the car there's an egg (`data`) and a note (`next`) saying "there's an egg in the garage". That's the third node.

In the garage there's an egg (`data`) and a note (`next`) saying "there aren't any more eggs" (a null pointer). That's the fourth node, the last one.

The notes don't "keep" each other, they don't "pass through" each other or anything like that. They're just notes.

When you write `head->next->next->data` it means: "Look at the `head` note in the kitchen (the compiler already knows where this one is). Then go to the place it says and look at the `next` note. Then go to the place it says and look at the `next` note. Then go to the place it says and look at the `data` egg."

The instructions don't make the *notes* do things (or the eggs) - they make *you* (the CPU) do things. The notes don't run around re-shuffling themselves - *you* run around looking at the notes.

Comment: So basically we assign the address of the next pointer to the head pointer and it continues like this?

Comment: @Mystheman If you want to delete the mailbox node from the linked list, you would throw out the egg and the note from the mailbox, and then go to the note on the kitchen, cross out "mailbox" and write "oven". Otherwise, no, you would not assign anything to the `head` note in the kitchen.